# How to record video that contains GPUImageUIElement with AlphaBlendFilter

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I tried to record video that contains UILabel as overlay using GPUImageUIElement and Alpha blend filter.. [image: the way I implemented]

While recording video It wont add that element (overlay) to video. How to solve this..

Comment: Any luck in solving this issue?

Comment: Found the solution to the problem here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679688/ios-save-gpuimage-video

The example is working with the UIElement example from GPUImage and is saving the overlay to the video while recording.